# How to get facebook api data using jQuery

Tags: php, jquery, facebook, facebook-php-sdk

I created a script to get the data from my fan page on facebook like this :

```
<?php
require '../src/facebook.php';
$facebook = new Facebook(array(
  'appId'  => '339554932739xxx',
  'secret' => 'acb1234def85858',
));

$pages = $facebook->api('/me/accounts');

foreach ($pages['data'] as $page) {
    $page_access_token = $page['access_token'];
    $page_conversations = $facebook->api('/234234234234/conversations', 'GET', array('access_token' => $page_access_token));
    echo "<pre>";
    var_dump($page_conversations);
    echo "</pre>";
}
```

That generates result the data like this :

http://pastebin.com/Ek9RCWtB

How do I get the data or retrieve data from the process with a $.ajax and $.each to loop this data ??

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

For each iteraion of the loop you shoud store the conversation (don't use echo or pre).

```
$pcs[] = $page_conversations;
```

At the end of the code echo the array as json.

```
echo json_encode($pcs);
```

Then use jquery to get the information as json

```
$.ajax({
    url : "path/to/thepage.php",
    dataType : "json",
    success : function(json) {
        for(var i in json) {
            alert(json[i]);
        }
    }
});
```

The full PHP code might look something like this.

```
<?php
require '../src/facebook.php';
$facebook = new Facebook(array(
  'appId'  => '339554932739xxx',
  'secret' => 'acb1234def85858',
));

$pages = $facebook->api('/me/accounts');

$pcs = array(); 
foreach ($pages['data'] as $page) {
    $page_access_token = $page['access_token'];
    $page_conversations = $facebook->api('/234234234234/conversations', 'GET', array('access_token' => $page_access_token));
    $pcs[] = $page_conversations;
}
echo json_encode($pcs);
```

Comment: Thanks for reply @Logan Murphy ,but I get an error : 500 Internal Server Error, while trying jquery

Comment: What if you just navigate to the page using a web browser? Is there an error log?

Comment: No...everything is fine... You can check : http://fbsdk.berthoservice.in/examples/proses.php

Comment: I am getting a 500 response when navigating to that page. See if on your server you have an error log. Maybe you need to declared the array before the loop. `$pcs = array();`

Comment: It should be okay if it is from a subdomain. As long as everything is using the same domain you should be fine.

Comment: Yes...I Already moved in same subdomain..I get a response, but why error? http://s11.postimg.org/clhj642ib/respon.png

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/48522/discussion-between-bertho-joris-and-logan-murphy)